# How do multiple Target Metric Aurora Autoscaling Policies interact?

Tags: mysql, connection, amazon-rds, autoscaling, amazon-aurora

I don't see anything in the docs about multiple target metric rules interacting, and if there is any sort of preference or logic involved:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html

For instance, do multiple target rules:

- apply so as to not violate the rule that needs to create a scale-out (more instance)?  e.g if I have a rule that tries to maintain 20% CPU usage, and one that tries to maintain 25 connections, and my servers have 10% CPU utilization but 100 connections each, will my instances a) scale in (become fewer), due to the CPU rule, or b) scale out, due to the connections rule?  I would hope scale out, since we clearly need them in this case.
- apply based on the order in which they're created/listed in the console?
- apply in order to respect/prioritize the scale in rule?
- ignore more than one rule?